# How can I refactoring CSS class names on public at Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, css, visual-studio, performance, automated-refactoring

I want to minimize CSS codes by renaming (refactoring) classnames in CSS and HTML in Visual Studio. But I only want to change names when I publish project.

Is there any way I can change CSS class names to short version in CSS and aspx files at phublis. For example .headerMenuBtn => a, headerMenuIcon => b etc.

Note:
1- I'm usin LESS to code CSS (but it is not importent to me if some tool can change in css filse)
2- My Visual Studio version is 2017

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. It is going to make coding little harder but I think end result worth it.

I created 3 different variables files.

1. cssClassName.less => for less usage
2. cssClassName.cs (under app_code) => for aspx usega
3. cssClassName_cs.cs (under app_code) => for cs usage

### FILES

**ClassName.less**

```
@responsive: a;
```

**cssClassName.cs => Build actin = content**

```
public class cssClassName
{
    public static string responsive = "a";
}
```

**cssClassName.cs => Build action = Compile**

```
public class cssClassName_cs
{
    public static string responsive = "a";
}
```

### USAGE

**aspx**

```
<div class="<%=cssClassName.responsive>">Test</div> => output = <div class="a">Test</div>
```

**less**

```
.@{responsive}{  => output = .a{width: 100%;}
    width: 100%;
}
```

**cs**

```
String html = "<div class=\" + cssClassName_cs.responsive + \">Test</div>"; => output = <div class="a">Test</div>
```

And end result cause much smaller HTML and CSS size.